# How do I ask and say "X is the nth president"

Tags: grammar

Trying to ask `"Which number president is Donald Trump"` and then `"Donald trump is the 45th President of the U.S."`

I think the first could be `どちらの大統領はXですか？` but it sounds too simplistic?

Comment: In this case, `第四十五代(四十五代目)の大統領` is appropriate, I think.